# Problem connecting the second external monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, external-monitor

I had a similar problem while using Ubuntu 10.04. I recently upgraded to 11.10 and when I connect the external monitor, both the screens( laptop screen and external monitor) goes dark and stops responding.

But, individual screens work perfectly fine. I cannot mirror the screen as well as it is disabled.

Any idea how to fix this problem ? I would like to extend my screen.

Thanks

Comment: What is your graphics card..

Comment: Its Intel 845 Chipset

Comment: What happens when you press the [fn][display-settings] key to cycles through the different hardware settings? Most laptops have a key like this.

Comment: I used a gnome-display settings to add the external monitors. The Fn keys in my Laptop dont work in Linux unfortunately :)

Comment: There are several bugs on the subject of external display. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/745112 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/614238 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/compiz/+bug/808677 and more

Answer (score 0):

A clean 11.10 install (32 bit) solved the problem.
(Don't forget to backup your valuables)